# Why my pdf file is not getting uploaded with express and multer?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern, multer

I have search alot but no able to find issue. Code is fine but my pdf file is not getting uploaded.

confguration

```
const multer = require("multer");

const pdfUpload = multer({
  limits: 50000000,
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      console.log(file);
      try {
        cb(null, "uploads/");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, "sheharyarCV.pdf");
    },
  }),
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const isValid = file.mimetype === "application/pdf" ? true : false;
    const error = isValid ? null : new Error("Issue with mimetype");
    cb(error, true);
  },
});

module.exports = pdfUpload;
```

Route

```
const express = require("express");
const pdfUpload = require("../middlewares/pdf-upload");

const updateAboutAndResumeHandler = require("../controllers/aboutAndResume-controller");

const router = express.Router();

router.patch("/", pdfUpload.single("resume"), updateAboutAndResumeHandler);

module.exports = router;
```

React code, I am using FormData for sending my data.

```
const formChangeHandler = async (data) => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("about", data.about);
      formData.append("resume", data.resume);
      const response = await fetch(
        `${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL}/api/about&resume`,
        {
          method: "PATCH",
          body: formData,
        }
      );
      const result = await response;

      console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    console.log(data);
    closePanel();
  };
```

I will be really gratefull if anyone can help.

Answer my question.
Why my pdf file is not uploading?

Comment: What version of multer are you using?
Are there any error messages?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I find the issue. It was the data I send. The file was coming as array in backend. So, I just change it into single value.